# (~INT_MAX && INT_MAX) returns 1?

Tags: c, expression, numeric-limits

I am under the impression that INT_MAX will turn on all 32 bits of an int. If I negate that and 'and' it with itself, I should be comparing all 0s with all 1s and get back false. What am I missing?

```
int x = INT_MAX;
x = ~x && INT_MAX;
printf("x = %d\n", x); /*Returns 1*/
x = 0;
x = ~x && INT_MAX;
printf("x = %d\n", x); /*Returns 1*/
```

Edit: Oh wow I was flipping the sign bit as well. Using UNIT_MAX is giving me the result I needed. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: *I am under the impression that INT_MAX will turn on all 32 bits of an int.* - you forgot about the sign bit.

Comment: `&&` is **logical** AND, not *bit-wise*.

Comment: "I am under the impression that INT_MAX will turn on all 32 bits of an int."  You are under the wrong impression.  Signed values use the MSb for denoting negative values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with **signed** ints here; `~INT_MAX == INT_MIN` (*edit*: for two's complement, which is what every modern processor uses), not 0. In C, all values except 0, including negatives, will evaluate to true when used in a conditional.

If you switch to unsigned types everything should work as expected since `~UINT_MAX == 0`.

Comment: `~INT_MAX == INT_MIN` - I think it is incorrect... Update: Well, correct for 2's complement.

Comment: @EugeneSh. On some obscure processor that does not use Two's Complement?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons A quick search is bringing this: https://superuser.com/questions/1137182/is-there-any-existing-cpu-implementation-which-uses-ones-complement Anyway, it's true in most cases, that's fine.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Don't get me wrong, I'm on your side there.  The C standard does not guarantee `~INT_MAX == INT_MIN`.  Won't find many processors these days for which it's not true, but it is always good to be aware of such possibilities.  And I'm all for a little pedantry here and there.

Comment: Agreed, it's an important point and I definitely should have had a note about it in my answer. I've added it, thanks :)

Comment: That said, it doesn't change the answer to the question.

Comment: I actually think that the real answer to the question is that the OP is using `&&` instead of `&`... but... OK :)

Comment: Hm, I don't *think* so since OP says "I should be comparing all 0s with all 1s and get back false" in the question, but it's definitely possible…

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to compare the bits. :)

Comment: But you are not comparing the bits. You get `1` since both `~x` and `INT_MAX` are non-zero. Regardless of which bits are non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I am under the impression that INT_MAX will turn on all 32 bits of an int.

No; it will only turn on the lower 31 bits of an `int`<sup>1</sup> - the uppermost (sign) bit will be left 0 to denote a positive value.  `~INT_MAX` corresponds to `~0x7FFFFFFF`, or `0x80000000`.

You're thinking of `UINT_MAX`.

---

1. Assuming a 32-bit `int`; some implementations may use wider integers.